# Form arrays with Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, arrays, forms, laravel, laravel-5

What is the most graceful way of creating a multidimensional form array using the `Form::` facade in Laravel 5.1?

I know that I can create form fields using the following syntax:

```
{!! Form::label('work_type', 'Work Type') !!}
{!! Form::select('work_type', WorkTypes::show(), ['id' => 'work_type']) !!}

{!! Form::label('date', 'Date &amp; Time Worked') !!}
{!! Form::text('date', date('d/m/Y'), ['id' => 'date', 'class' => 'datepicker']) !!}

{!! Form::label('overtime_start_hour', 'Overtime Start Hour') !!}
{!! Form::select('overtime_start_hour', Hours::show(), ['id' => 'overtime_start_hour']) !!}

{!! Form::label('overtime_start_minute', 'Overtime Start Minute') !!}
{!! Form::select('overtime_start_minute', Minutes::show(), ['id' => 'overtime_start_minute']) !!}
```

However, i'm looking to create a multidimensional form array.  I would want the array to look something like this when the form is submitted:

```
array(
    [0] => 
        [work_type]             => 'My work type value for row 1...',
        [date]                  => '20/03/2015',
        [overtime_start_hour]   => array(
                                    [0] => 01
                                    [1] => 03
                                )
        [overtime_start_minute] => array(
                                    [0] => 00
                                    [1] => 00
                                )
    [1] => 
        [work_type]             => 'My work type value for row 2...',
        [date]                  => '21/03/2015',
        [overtime_start_hour]   => array(
                                    [0] => 09
                                    [1] => 07
                                )
        [overtime_start_minute] => array(
                                    [0] => 30
                                    [1] => 00
                                )
)
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: where is the variable you get the data ? can you please show me?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean?  Sorry, which variable are you referring to?  I basically want to setup my Laravel form to output an array like the one above.  I'm just asking how I would create something like that.

Comment: For you to get your desired outputted array. Can you give me the data's fetched in your code?

Comment: I have not written that part of the code yet, I am just at the point of creating the form.  I am not processing the form just yet...

Comment: Use foreach sir @V4n1ll4

Comment: @aldrin27 please read the question again.

Answer (score 1):

Change your selects to multiples, and the names to arrays, as such:

```
{!! Form::select('overtime_start_hour[]', Hours::show(), null, ['id' => 'overtime_start_hour', 'multiple' => true]) !!}

{!! Form::select('overtime_start_minute[]', Minutes::show(), null, ['id' => 'overtime_start_minute', 'multiple' => true]) !!}
```

You can then select multiple items from the select boxes, and get the array you're after. Is that how you wanted it to work?

**Edit:** you could try adding a row array to all the fields when you add a new row, and increment the row ID and form input ID time

```
{!! Form::label('work_type0', 'Work Type') !!}
{!! Form::select('row[0][work_type]', WorkTypes::show(), null, ['id' => 'work_type0']) !!}

{!! Form::label('date0', 'Date &amp; Time Worked') !!}
{!! Form::text('row[0][date]', date('d/m/Y'), null, ['id' => 'date0', 'class' => 'datepicker']) !!}

{!! Form::label('overtime_start_hour0', 'Overtime Start Hour') !!}
{!! Form::select('row[0][overtime_start_hour]', Hours::show(), null, ['id' => 'overtime_start_hour0']) !!}

{!! Form::label('overtime_start_minute0', 'Overtime Start Minute') !!}
{!! Form::select('row[0][overtime_start_minute]', Minutes::show(), null, ['id' => 'overtime_start_minute0']) !!}
```

Next row (obviously)...

```
{!! Form::label('work_type1', 'Work Type') !!}
{!! Form::select('row[1][work_type]', WorkTypes::show(), null, ['id' => 'work_type1']) !!}
```

Comment: Hi @benJ !  Thanks but this will not work as I need it to unfortunately.  On the page, the user has the ability to add new rows.  The fields above are childs of these rows and therefore it would not be possible to go down the route of the multiple select.  The user clicks Add new row and it adds a new row containing the fields above, which is why they need to be single selects.

Comment: Ah ok, I've edited... is that more what you had in mind?

Comment: Just a quick note: Form::select() takes one additional argument - the default/preset value - where I've added null :)